# SUMIFS returning to zero when reference criteria ranges on different sheet of workbook

Tags: excel, sumifs

I can't get my SUMIFS function on my second sheet to reference the data in the other sheet of the workbook. The formula is

`=SUMIFS('Detailed Co Ag Com'!C7:$C$3485, 'Detailed Co Ag Com'!A7:$A$3485, $B$11, 'Detailed Co Ag Com'!B7:$B$3485, $D$2)`

Cells B11 and D2 contain text and are on the sheet I'm writing the formula in, column A and B are also formatted as text. Column C is formatted as number.

The formula works if all of it is on the first sheet.
`=SUMIFS(C7:C3485, A7:A3485,K4, B7:B3485, L3)`

Comment: I have recreated the 2 worksheet setup you describe, but I don't get any errors and it runs fine for me. My best guess for why the first formula returns 0 but the second one does not would be because the criteria cells might be different? (e.g. B11 vs K4, D2 vs L3)

Comment: Sample data or a screenshot might be helpful here.